# How to display extended offer below specific table row?

Tags: angularjs

I have this table.I have details on every row and my idea is when user click on that details to expend another row below that row but problem is that it always expand at the bottom of page.I need to expand below specific row where i click.Any suggestion? This is my html for that table :

```
<div class="table-layout clean-table">
    <table class="table responsive-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>@Translator.Translate("STATUS")</th>
                <th>@Translator.Translate("ID_TICKET_NUMBER")</th>
                <th>@Translator.Translate("TICKET_TIME")</th>
                <th>@Translator.Translate("PAYIN_AMOUNT")</th>
                <th>@Translator.Translate("PAYOUT_AMOUNT")</th>
                <th>@Translator.Translate("TICKET_DETAIL")</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="tickets in GetAllTickets">
                <th><img ng-src="~/Content/img/Icons/{{tickets.Status | lowercase}}.png" /></th>
                <th>{{tickets.Pin}}</th>
                <th>{{tickets.TimeCreated |  date: 'dd.MM.yyyy - hh:mm:ss'}}</th>
                <th>{{tickets.PayIn}}</th>
                <th>{{tickets.PayoutAmount}}</th>
                <th><button class="details" ng-click="toggleExpandOffer($event);PinTicketSearch(tickets.Pin)"></button></th>

            </tr>
            <!--extended-->
            <tr class="extended-offer-container-row" ng-class=" {'expanded':isExpanded}">
                <th colspan="14">
                    <div ng-slide-down="isExpanded" duration="0.3" lazy-render>
                        <table class="offer-table-extended">

                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="popup-text">@Translator.Translate("DATE"):</td>
                                                <td class="white">{{ TicketDetail != null ? TicketDetail.BettingSlipResult.TicketHolder.Date : TopTicket.TimeCreated }} {{ TicketDetail != null ? TicketDetail.BettingSlipResult.TicketHolder.Time : '' }}</td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="popup-text">
                                                    @Translator.Translate("GAME_TYPE"):
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="white">{{ TicketDetail != null ? TicketDetail.BettingSlipResult.TicketHolder.GameType : TopTicket.GameType }}</td>
                                            </tr>

                                        </table>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>


                                <div ng-if="TicketDetail.BettingSlipResult.TicketHolder.BingoBets.length >= 1">
                                    <table class="ticket-table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th class="text-center">@Translator.Translate("PICK")</th>
                                                <th class="text-center">@Translator.Translate("ROUND_NUMBER")</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr ng-repeat="a in TicketDetail.BettingSlipResult.TicketHolder.BingoBets">
                                                <td>{{a.Pick}}</td>
                                                <td>{{a.RoundNumber}}</td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>


                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>


</div>
```

Comment: Use ng-repeat-start (for your "normal" row) and ng-repeat-end for your expanded row: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points. You'll thus have 2 rows per item, and you can choose to make the second one visible or not depending on which item is expanded.

Comment: Part of your problem is the `BettingSlipResult div` needs to either be in a table cell, or outside of the `<table>` completely.

Comment: @JBNizet so i need directive for this ng-repeat-start ?

Comment: @ParrisVarney i fix that..tnx :)

Comment: @None no. This directive exists, and I gave you the direct link to its documentation, which also contains an example. Read it.

Comment: @JbNizet where ever i put ng-end it say that is not okay ? Maybe this is not for my structure of html?

Comment: I can't tell you how to fix an error without knowing the code causing the error and the error message.

Comment: Unterminated attribute, found 'ng-repeat-start' but no matching 'ng-repeat-end' found. This is i get

Answer (score 0):

You can move ng-repeat to the tbody element instead of the tr element:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="tickets in GetAllTickets">
```

There will be multiple tbody elements but this is valid html. Since there will be multiple extended `<tr class="extended-offer-container-row" ng-class=" {'expanded':isExpanded}">` instead of the one now, you can update that to reference `tickets` which is now in it's scope.

Comment: when i move ng-repeat to <tbody> when i click on one row...they all opens

Comment: You'll need to use an ng-show on <tr class="extended-offer-container-row" ng-class=" {'expanded':isExpanded}"> so that only one is displayed.